# Nunit-console Incorrect parameter

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm currently trying to update some of the build nodes of our Jenkins setup from Nunit console 3.6.0 to Nunit console 3.7.0

In the old Nunit console we used via the bat call:

```
"E:\tools\NUnit.Console-3.6.0\nunit3-console.exe" --result="unittests.xml;format=nunit2" "some.dll" "another.dll"
```

With Nunit console 3.6.0 this was working. With 3.7.0 it fails on a incorrect argument (see console output below). I can't figure out witch parameter it is that is incorrect. To my knowledge all of the parameters supplied are still supported in 3.7.0

Inside the solution Nunit 3.9 is used via the NuGet package. I already tried downgrading to 3.8 but that didn't help

full log for `"E:\tools\NUnit.Console-3.7.0\nunit3-console.exe" --result="unittests.xml;format=nunit2" [list of dll's]`:

```
14:04:18 NUnit Console Runner 3.7.0 
14:04:18 Copyright (c) 2017 Charlie Poole, Rob Prouse
14:04:18 
14:04:19 Runtime Environment
14:04:19    OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
14:04:19   CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000
14:04:19 
14:04:19 Test Files
14:04:19     EplanImporterTests\bin\Debug\EplanImporterTests.dll
14:04:19     MachineConfiguratorTests\bin\Debug\MachineConfiguratorTests.dll
14:04:19     TSMFileGeneratorTests\bin\Debug\TSMFileGeneratorTests.dll
14:04:19     TsmBlockTypesTests\bin\Debug\TsmBlockTypesTests.dll
14:04:19     ValidationFrameworkTests\bin\Debug\EplanImporterTests.dll
14:04:19     ValidationFrameworkTests\bin\Debug\TSMFileGeneratorTests.dll
14:04:19     ValidationFrameworkTests\bin\Debug\ValidationFrameworkTests.dll
14:04:19     ValidatorFrameworkTests\bin\Debug\ValidatorFrameworkTests.dll
14:04:19 
14:04:23 
14:04:23 Errors, Failures and Warnings
14:04:23 
14:04:23 1) Error : E:\DEV-BLD-SVR02\workspace\NunitUpdateedbae018\EplanImporterTests\bin\Debug\EplanImporterTests.dll
14:04:23 The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
14:04:23 
14:04:23 Server stack trace: 
14:04:23    at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GetLocationEvidence(SafePEFileHandle peFile, SecurityZone& zone, StringHandleOnStack retUrl)
14:04:23    at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateLocationEvidence()
14:04:23    at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
14:04:23    at System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
14:04:23    at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
14:04:23    at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)
14:04:23    at System.Security.Policy.AppDomainEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
14:04:23    at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
14:04:23    at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.RawEvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
14:04:23    at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.EvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
14:04:23    at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.get_Count()
14:04:23    at NUnit.Engine.Services.DomainManager.CreateDomain(TestPackage package)
14:04:23    at NUnit.Engine.Runners.TestDomainRunner.LoadPackage()
14:04:23    at NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.EnsurePackageIsLoaded()
14:04:23    at NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
14:04:23    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
14:04:23    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
14:04:23 
14:04:23 Exception rethrown at [0]: 
14:04:23    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
14:04:23    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
14:04:23    at NUnit.Engine.ITestEngineRunner.Run(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
14:04:23    at NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
```

It repeats the same error for all other dll's that where getting tested

Comment: The incorrect parameter isn't an NUnit Console command line parameter, but an incorrect parameter somewhere in the .NET Framework stack when NUnit is creating a separate `AppDomain` to run your tests in. The call to `System.Security.Policy.Evidence` is failing. Has anything else changed on your build machine?

Comment: The code in NUnit that is failing is `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence` which shouldn't fail. Possibly related to https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/3041857/-code-0x80070057-the-parameter-is-incorrect-error-when-you-try-to-disp?

Comment: @RobProuse the storage location of the Nunit console. It used to stand on the C drive but we moved it to a network drive (E) so we wouldn't have to go over all build nodes to update them. could that have an effect? judging by the link you just posted: yes, probaply. I'll move it to the C drive and test if it works

Comment: That is likely the issue. The link above points to a Server 2012 hotfix for getting access permissions on fileshares. I expect that copying the Evidence does this.

Comment: You can add NUnit Console as a NuGet package for your solution and reference it from there. That is the way most people get it onto their build machines.

Comment: @RobProuse It works, I moved the Nunit console to the C drive and now it is running as expected. You can post it as an answer if you want and I'll accept it. Out of curiosity though, how does that work via a nuget package? How can I get Jenkins to the point where it will use the included nuget package to run the, also, included unit tests?

Comment: @NickOtten This is possibly https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/311? I realise the issue title isn't the most searchable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incorrect parameter isn't an NUnit Console command line parameter, but an incorrect method parameter in the .NET Framework stack when calling `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence`. It is likely caused by an [issue with Server 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/3041857/-code-0x80070057-the-parameter-is-incorrect-error-when-you-try-to-disp) where it fails to find file permissions on mapped network drives.

The simplest workaround is to move NUnit console onto a real drive, or install NUnit console as a NuGet package. To use the NuGet package, add a the [NUnit.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.Console/) package to one of your test projects. When the project builds, it will be installed at `$(SolutionRoot)\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.7.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe`. Just reference that copy of the Console Runner when you setup your tests. For you, probably modify your BAT file to use a relative path.

Note that the directory under packages is `NUnit.ConsoleRunner` not the installed package `NUnit.Console`. This is because `NUnit.Console` is a meta-package that installs the runner `NUnit.ConsoleRunner` and a number of extensions like support for the NUnit 2 result format which you need.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with the problem and for pointing me the way to an even better solution :)